# An application initiated by C# stays as running process until main thread closes

Tags: c#, com, process

My aim here is to control a 3rd party application using C#. The 3rd party application can be controlled by COM references.

I've added the reference in my simple console application and I can see the classes and methods no problem.

The following line triggers the 3rd party application to launch. Which it does. You can see it happily sitting there in Taskmanager/Processes (mfl32.exe):

```
MFL32.Application mfl = new MFL32.Application();
```

When my console application exits mfl32.exe is still in the processes list - which is to be expected as I made no call to close it. I then added this line:

```
mfl.Quit();
```

Now when my console application runs it triggers mfl32.exe to be started and when my console application closes it terminates the mfl32.exe process.

The problem arises is that my code requires calls to this application to be made in a separate thread. The mfl32.exe process doesn't terminate at the end of thread and will only remove itself when my console application closes. The current code looks like this:

```
namespace lt
{

class threadtest
{
    public void LaserTest()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Worker thread started...");
        MFL32.Application mfl = new MFL32.Application();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 50000)
        {
            i++;
        }
        mfl.Quit();
        Console.WriteLine("Worker thread now finished!");
    }

    void laser_AppQuit() // Quit event handler triggered
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The QUIT method has been caught. It should kill the lfm32.exe process");
    }
}



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        threadtest workerObject = new threadtest();
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.LaserTest);
        workerThread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("End of main thread reached");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Any idea's as to why the triggered exe only terminates when the main console application terminates not when it reaches the end of a separate thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd-party program probably stays alive while there are outstanding COM references to it, even after calling `mfl.Quit()`. That's a bit odd because the normal semantic of a "Quit()" method would be to force a process to exit (orderly) and invalidate any COM references.

By design, .Net doesn't call Release() on a COM object when the variable holding the reference (Ok, the variable holding the reference to the [RCW or Runtime-Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx) object that holds a COM reference to the application) goes out of scope, because .Net is garbage-collected.

`Release()` will only be called on a COM object when your process (technically the AppDomain) ends, or when the garbage collector decides to collect your RCW objects, which on a short-lived console application would be 'never'.

I would have expected that RCW objects would be `Dispose()`able, but they are not. Maybe there is a technical reason, maybe the dispose pattern wasn't introduced until it was too late in the development process of .Net 1.0 to change the behavior of RCW's.

In any case, to force a RCW to call `Release()` on its COM reference, call:

```
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mfl);
```

Try that after calling the `Quit()` method and see if it changes the behavior of the third-party program.

Comment: This works perfectly. Much more friendly than capturing the quit event then trying to kill the process manually! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume something is not being released correctly in the COM dll. I would try running the LaserTest in separate application domain. Once assembly is loaded in .NET, it stays loaded unless app domain is destroyed. Alternatively, you can create separate "launcher" assembly, run the launcher assembly in your thread and force exit in launcher assembly, once it is done with the COM stuff. As for running in separate application domain:

```
  var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("LaserDomain");
  domain.DoCallBack(() => {
      // dummy wait - run laser test here
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
  });
```